# jquery window resize help please

Tags: jquery, resize, window

$(window).resize(foo())

to detect when the window is resizeing...

the foo() works fine but it only fires foo() after the resize has finished so it's not while resizeing.

is there a way to make the resize smoothly. maybe a cancelBubble could be something to do with it but im not familiar with it.

Comment: `foo` shouldn't have the parentheses.  What you want, typically, is to pass in a reference to the function, not execute it and pass the result which is what happens when you include the parentheses.  Of course, this could just be a transcription error...and it's not an answer to your question, obviously.

Comment: am not sure i understand what u mean

Comment: When you follow a function with parentheses, you are calling the function at that point. What you want is just `$(window).resize(foo)` or `$(window).resize(function() {...})`, which supplies a reference to the function to be executed later to the resize method.

Comment: I used $(window).resize(foo); it works fine on ie. except ff not so well. i don't think its a big issue but it would be nice if this worked when window starts resizing or while resizing instead of when resize stop. i guess it must be a browser issue and not a js issue thanks for your help

Comment: This post might address this problem: > [Debounced resize() jQuery plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do precisely what you want by listening to window `resize` events.

Check out Google maps or reader, try resizing the window vertically. Note that these apps exhibit the same behavior.

Look a bit more carefully at your CSS. I find that sometimes CSS can do some very surprising things. If you post some sample HTML and CSS that is representative of you problem, we may be able to devise a solution.

If you absolutely cannot tolerate waiting until the user has finished resizing the window, you could poll `document.scrollWidth` and `document.scrollHeight` at a short interval. Whenever they change, call your resizing code. Note that polling these properties may be pretty expensive. I recommend against this, but it will solve the problem.

If you are using Internet Explorer, depending on version, you made need to use `document.documentElement.scrollWidth` or `document.body.scrollWidth` (and similar for `scrollWidth`).

Firefox 3.6 will support events for determining when `document.scrollWidth` and `document.scrollHeight` change, although it looks like it will be non-standard:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Detecting_document_width_and_height_changes

Answer (score 2):

The resize event fired after the window has finished resizing is pretty much the way things are. I don't think you can do anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery documentation, you seem to be experiencing Firefox behavior when you're really after IE behavior.

> Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in Firefox). http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Interestingly, on that same page is a comment to a plugin which may make the behavior cross-browser (I have not looked into this)

Answer (score 0):

It makes me wonder why you would want to do such a thing. If you could be specific, perhaps I could suggest a CSS solution to you?

Comment: well i am using it so i can change the height of the a class. more like a fluid concept and css cant do that because there are different factors that mess it up.